# Replace/Escape single quotes in sqlite on left join string

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SQL-Query

It is comparing the item Name to the Name of the Project to check if it overlaps. 
Not if i have a single quote ' in the Project or SubProject my query fails. 
How can i escape the singe quote in my LIKE?

My Databases Look like this

```
TItems
Name
-------
testitem
te'stitem

TProject
Project
--------
test
te'st
```

My SQL query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM TItems AS items
LEFT JOIN TProject AS projs
ON LOWER(items.Name) LIKE '%'||LOWER(projs.Project)||'%'
```

The result should be

```
Name       | Project
testitem   | test
te'stsitem | te'st
```

however it chrashe because i have a single quote in my likes. How can I escape them. These are values from the db.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Like works fine with single quotes. LOWER function not needed to still make the match, but doesn't hurt either.  There is no way to get your query to crash.